# Why Scrapy keeps showing the error message of "Loading scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http.HTTPDownloadHandler" for scheme "http"

Tags: python, macos, scrapy

I am running a Scrapy project on my Mac arm64 for the first time. Regardless of the starting URL, the Scrapy program keeps showing the error message:

```
 "Loading scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http.HTTPDownloadHandler" for scheme "http"
```

Following are my specs:

```
OS: Mac Sonoma 14.1.2
Chip: Apple M1
Scrapy version: 2.11
Twisted version: 22.10
Virtual_env python: 3.9.18
```

I have tried to reinstall `Scrapy` and upgrade the Twisted to the latest version.
[example code and traceback message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVyxF.png)

Comment: Can't do nothing without a code example and error trace.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have added a pic of example code and the trace back message.

Comment: Re/Install scrapy in a dedicated virtual environment and try again.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this same problem, deinstalling `attr` and re-installing it solved the problem:

```
pip3 uninstall attr
pip3 install attr
```